# How do I handle a posted String array in servlet?

Tags: java, arrays, ajax, servlets, request

In my form the user can check several checkboxes before posting the form to the servlet:

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="1"><label for="1">First Person Shooter</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="2"><label for="2">Sports</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="3"><label for="3">Action/Adventure</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="4"><label for="4">Educational</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="5"><label for="5">Puzzle</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="6"><label for="6">Real Time Strategy</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="7"><label for="7">Beat em ups</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="genre" name="genre[]" value="8"><label for="8">Survival Horror</label><br>
```

I post the form data to the servlet using an AJAX call and serializing the form data like this:

```
$(".mainSurvey").submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var postData    = $(".mainSurvey").serializeArray();
    var botCatcher  = $("#botCatcher").val();

    if($(".mainSurvey input:checkbox:checked").length > 0 && botCatcher.length == 0){

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url : "DatabaseService",
            data : postData,
            success: function(data) 
            {
                // continue
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                // handle error
            });

        }else{
            // handle error
        }
});
```

Where I would usually access a text inputs value using:

`String input = request.getParameter("input");`

How do I access the array of checkbox values within the servlet after posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Servlet API docs:

> getParameter
>
> public java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name) Returns
>   the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter
>   does not exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the
>   request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query
>   string or posted form data. **You should only use this method when you
>   are sure the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have
>   more than one value, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).**
>
> **If you use this method with a multivalued parameter, the value
>   returned is equal to the first value in the array returned by
>   getParameterValues.**
>
> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs
>   with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via
>   getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of
>   this method.
>
> Parameters: name - a String specifying the name of the parameter
>   Returns: a String representing the single value of the parameter See
>   Also: getParameterValues(java.lang.String)